# Template template parameter in VS2015

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015, template-templates

I have faced with curious issue.
Given Template class and template function:

```
template<typename L, typename T>
class TemplateClass
{
public:

   int operator()()
   {
      return 1;
   }
};

template<typename K, template<typename L, 
                              typename T = int> class TemplateCl>
TemplateCl<K> getTemplateClass(TemplateCl<K> _cls)
{
   TemplateCl<K> cls;
   return cls;
}

int main()
{
    auto templateClass = TemplateClass<int,int>();
    auto rTemplateClass = getTemplateClass<int>(templateClass);
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles by Clang, but when I try to compile with VS2015 it fails:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2672   'getTemplateClass': no matching overloaded function found   cpp11_cpp14_cpp17   d:\projects_programing\__testing\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17.cpp  682 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'TemplateCl<K,int> getTemplateClass(TemplateCl<K,int>)'  cpp11_cpp14_cpp17   d:\projects_programing\__testing\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17.cpp  682
```

This code compiles only with the following modifications:

```
template<typename L, typename T = int>
class TemplateClass
{
public:

   int operator()()
   {
      return 1;
   }
};
```

The most wierd situation that it even compiles with the following modification:

```
template<typename L, typename T = float>
class TemplateClass
{
public:

   int operator()()
   {
      return 1;
   }
};
```

Is it an issue on VS2015 compiler ?
Does anybody know why VS2015 has such wierd behaviour ?